# Using kong-jwt2header plugin to get the claims in upstream

Tags: jwt, microservices, kong

I have installed the **kong-jwt2header** plugin in the Kong with configuration `config.token_required=true`.

I also have configured the Identity service in kong which is used to generate the JWT token. As we set the `config.token_required=true` in kong-jwt2header plugin throws an error `{"error": "No valid JWT token found"}` while requesting a JWT token from the Identity service.

Now I have two options

1. Set the `config.token_required=false` Or
2. Keep the Identity service outside the Kong gateway.
   So that JWT token is not required while requesting a token from an identity service.

Which is the best way from the above two? Or are there any better ways we can send the claims upstream?

Comment: You probably were using the plugin in global mode, using it per service/route would resolve the problem.